# ipad to ipad file transfer via wifi

Tags: ios, ipad, wifi, file-transfer

What is the best method to transfer file via wifi from one ipad to another?I  know how to handle the wifi network connection.But i need to know the most efficient way to transfer imajges , video etc from one ipad to another

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket - you can use it as a TCP server/client to transfer files between ipads.

I've used it between a laptop and iPad, but it will work iPad to iPad also.

Comment: looks like it might have moved here since then: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket