# transfer image and video files between ipad devices

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, network-programming, file-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ipad to ipad file transfer via wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570929/ipad-to-ipad-file-transfer-via-wifi)

In my application i am using to sync image and video files from my device  with another device(i pad).

so i need to send a image and video files through wifi to another device with a text(file name).

the images/videos are large sized(up to 20 MB).may i know how can i do that?

i am using currently  wifi network text transfer that referred from "Wi-tap" application from developer.apple

i downloaded the "Simple Network Streams" application from developer .apple...is there any good sample codes than it

any help full links or sample application path.